# Detect OS of VNC server

Tags: c#, vnc

**Scenario:**
I have written a code which connects to VNC server on default port 5900.

**Problem:**
How to get the OS name or details of VNC server?

Answer (score 0):

[Hope this link will help you](http://www.vpslinux.ga/2015/10/how-to-set-up-vnc-server-and-destop.html)
run

lsb_release -d
which should give you the the description including the OS name ("Ubuntu" on an Ubuntu system) and the release number.

lsb_release -c
will give you just the codename (e.g., "precise" for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

For the release number only, use

lsb_release -r
For all lsb version details, use

lsb_release -a

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am still curious for windows way of getting remote OS info.